# Find all occurrences of "int" or "integer" in all files in a folder and replace with "long"

Tags: unix, text, replace

I have a set of .xml files in a folder "model" with stuff like:

```
   <property name="manager"
          type="string"
          column="manager" />
    <property name="age"
          type="integer"
          column="age" />
```

And a java mapping file with stuff like:

```
class ClassName()
{
    int age;
    int getAge();
    setAge(int age); 
}
```

I basically need to remove ALL occurrences of int and Integer with long.

Is there a waylike a unix command or script that I can do that? I'm using RHEL5.

Comment: Most text editors have a find and replace for files in folders. Notepad++ can do this. http://superuser.com/questions/96148/how-to-use-notepad-on-redhat Does that help ? I cant remember ifyou can write a grep with some regular expressions that will find and replace.

Comment: Use Ctrl + H, in notepad find type="integer" replace type="long"

Comment: Can I write it across all files in all folders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find . -type f \( -name '*.xml' -o -name '*.java' \) \
  -exec sed -ri.back 's/\<int(eger)?\>/long/g' {} +
```

Or if you want to only process the files that do contain the string:

```
find . -type f \( -name '*.xml' -o -name '*.java' \) \
  -exec grep -ilZE '\<int(eger)\>' {} + |
  xargs -r0 sed -ri.back 's/\<int(eger)?\>/long/g'
```

Note that the above `sed`, `xargs` and `grep` commands use non standard extensions but would work with the GNU variants as found on Linux distributions including RHEL5.

The `.back` after `-i` is to save a backup copy of the original file and can be omitted if you don't need it.